# is compilation and installation possible on two different machines ?

Tags: cmake, pythonanywhere, make-install

I have developed an Django app that uses few python dependencies that uses a software called "openbabel-2.4.2", which can be compiled through "Cmake" when I am trying to install this "openbabel-2.4.2" on "pythonanywhere.com" free account, compilation terminated during "make". Because of pythonanywhere.com's policy, is that, you can't use 100%  CPU for a long time (more than 2-5 minutes).

Is there any way through which I could build and compile  "openbabel-2.4.2" somewhere on my personel computer and then could transfer the folder to remote server for "make install"

It may look stupidity at first glance but I think this could solve my problem.

thanks

Comment: You may **pack** your project using [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cpack.1.html) on *host* machine (PC case), and then unpack on the *target* machine (server in your case).

Comment: can i pack After Cmake compilation or we have to build packages with CPack instead of Cmake

Comment: I am not sure, but CPack adds some variable for CMake when perform project's configuration and building. I think you need to drive whole configuration and building process with CPack. Is this a problem in your case?

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here: if you build your package for 64-bit Ubuntu then it should work on our servers.

Comment: @GilesThomas thanks for your reply,  you mean to say if will build it on  Ubuntu 16 with my PC and then will transfer that folder to pythonanywhere is should work.

Comment: i think so. but also- maybe just upgrade your account (so u get 1000+ cpu seconds), and compile the code.

Comment: @conrad I don't want to upset any pythonanywhere developer but actually I don't want to upgrade with pythonanywhere their prices are too  high in compare to  other VPS providers. Since I am a bigginer so I just want to try something with free account first  and if everything goes right then only I will go for any upgrade wither its from pythonanywhere or  any other VPS service provider. thanks

Comment: Ah, good point -- Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit is the version you need.